# Having multiple classes that share the same instance variables for context consistency

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I am wondering if it is an acceptable approach to pass instance variables from one object to an object of another class (saving them as instance variables as well) in order to retain the context that is expressed by those instance variables.

In my case I have a ClassB with a method whose return value is needed to create objects of ClassA however this return value only makes sense in the context of certain instance variables of ClassB. Any suggestions how to approach this issue other than just passing the required instances variables from ClassB to ClassA?

Comment: You're a little light on details. It sounds like your mind is already made up that you have to save these instance variables. But depending on how you are architecting things, when does ClassB need to be made? Maybe you never have to store any variables at all. It's impossible to know without more design details.

Comment: The object of ClassB is set from start while an object of ClassA is created after running the method of the ClassB method. Later on the ClassA object is used for user interaction (data visualization, etc.).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with passing objects from one object to another-- you can't really write a program without doing this-- and storing them in more than one place is also very common. I am left wondering if OP is thinking of some specific situation because otherwise this seems like a nutty question.

Comment: The passing around part is of course mandatory and common. I am mostly wondering when storing the same stuff in more than one place becomes a bad design.

Comment: The only time I can think where it might be somewhat bad to store a reference in more than one place is if you are using a language that uses reference counting to know when to release resources, i.e. does not have garbage collection. What language are you writing your program in?

Comment: I'm going to have to reiterate my first comment: not enough information. A 5gb byte array is an instance member, so is an int. So you haven't told us size which is probably like the most important thing. I will also state the obvious, why not just make the instance variables in ClassA accessible to ClassB and ClassB can check on them before returning the object?

Comment: "this return value only makes sense in the context of certain instance variables of ClassB" - sounds like you have an unrecognized object in there, composed out of several related variables, that you keep track of in your mind (and/or in notes, documentation), instead of representing it in the code itself, as its own thing. Can you bundle these instance vars together in an object, add some methods that will provide answers to questions ClassA and ClassB might be interested in, and return the bundle instead (or a copy of it)?

Comment: This questions would heavily improve from some pseudo code. Voting to close with "needs details or clarity" until the OP fixes this.

Answer (score 2):

> Any suggestions how to approach this issue other than just passing the required instances variables from ClassB to ClassA?

Object composition is one option: pass a reference to a ClassB object to ClassA (in construction) instead of its individual instance fields, is the most obvious alternative.

If that is not appropriate, then sometimes that is because there is a missing abstraction.  For example, perhaps some subset of ClassB — representing a meaningful binding of items together into its own smaller abstraction — can be shared by both a ClassB instance and ClassA instance without ClassA having to have a reference to ClassB (or a copy of the fields of the smaller abstraction).

---

- The items being bound together as fields in a class should all have the same lifetime and serve the purpose of that class and its abstraction.  For example, if there are differing lifetimes of instance fields of the same class, then that is another kind indication that perhaps two abstractions are being conflated.
- Within reason, a consuming client would prefer to deal with a single item rather than multiple items that are meaningful as pairs (or together such).  Two individual measures that a client pairs to use, vs. a two dimensional coordinate as a higher abstraction, for example.